# Is there an axiom for ZFC that totally orders Cichon's diagram without collapsing it?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axioms

Is there a known axiom for ZFC that:

1. Fixes a total ordering on the cardinal numbers appearing in [Cichon's diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicho%C5%84%27s_diagram#Diagram).
2. Is "natural looking" - in particular, its not allowed to be a conjunction of statements asserting that one particular cardinal is less than another, or anything else artificial like that.
3. Does not allow us to prove any equalities between the cardinal numbers in Cichon's diagram, except for an equality corresponding to the requirement that $\mathrm{add}(\mathcal{K}) = \mathrm{min}\{\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal{K}),\mathfrak{b}\},$ and another corresponding to $\mathrm{cof}(\mathcal{K}) = \mathrm{max}\{\mathrm{non}(\mathcal{K}),\mathfrak{d}\}.$

Comment: Seeing how there is only one paper (and it's quite recent) that had dealt with separation of more than two invariants, I doubt there is anything like that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, thanks for the comment.

Comment: I'd wait for Arthur Fischer, he wrote that paper, he probably knows more.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: There is more than one paper by now (there are some recent papers by Diego Mejia and also a paper by Shelah and me that will be uploaded to arxiv soon :)).

Comment: @Haim: I see, post an answer with more details, then. Also, I sent you an email.